# Trying to end while loop Python

Tags: python

I have the following code that should end when my number is no longer a certain tuple, such as (1,0) or (2,0). But when I run my code it runs infinitely or not at all cant figure out the problem.

```
import random

START = (random.randrange(0, 4), random.randrange(0, 4))

print(START)

while START==(1, 0) or (2, 0) or (1, 1) or (3, 2):

    START = (random.randrange(0, 4), random.randrange(0, 4))

else:

    print(START)
```

Comment: very common mistake with `or`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a common error, evaluating an argument followed by OR and different values will always evaluate to true. You can read a more in-depth answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20002503/why-does-a-x-or-y-or-z-always-evaluate-to-true).

A good solution to avoid having to write multiple comparisons is to use the operator `in`. Replace:

```
while START==(1, 0) or (2, 0) or (1, 1) or (3, 2):
```

With

```
while START in [(1,0),(2,0),(1,1),(3,2)]:
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment! I have edited the answer to fix the typo.

Comment: Missed that, in fact I meant to say always instead of almost, because it's the title of the question asked in 2013 :P

Answer (score 1):

try

`while START==(1, 0) or START==(2, 0) or START==(1, 1) or START==(3, 2):`

or

`while START in [(1, 0), (2, 0), (1, 1), (3,2)]:`

the `else` shouldn't be needed.

Answer (score 0):

Your `while` condition is incorrect causing it to be in a infinite loop. Either try doing `while START==(1, 0) or START==(2, 0) or START==(1, 1) or START==(3, 2):` or put the tuples into a list and just do `START` in list.